# Hide PHP errors in ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, expressionengine

I recently switched hosts with a new PHP version. I'm getting an error from a plugin (Calendar) that just won't go away. It's a non-static method error that is causing 0 issues and it can't be fixed without trying a different plugin. I'm at the point where I just need it gone so this ugly message isn't showing on every page and I'll debug it later. I have tried disabling errors, setting every debug setting I can find to 0, but this error message won't go away! It's showing to everyone. What setting am I missing???

I've set the index.php debug=0

I've set the config.php $config['debug'] = 0;

I've added in an extra ini_set for display_errors and error_reporting to 0

I've double checked that the settings in the config file editor and output and debugging pages are showing 0

Why aren't any of these settings working? I'm using EE 2.5.5

Comment: What is your `error_reporting` set to in `php.ini`

Comment: Looks like 22527. And display_errors is set to off. I have error_reporting(0); and ini_set('display_errors', 0); in the index.php and config.php files

Comment: Not very helpfull: I worked with ExpressionEngine once and I pity you. A quick google: ExpressionEngine will only report PHP errors to the browser if the logged in user is in the Super Admin group. Do you also see these errors not being a super admin?

Comment: Yes, they are showing to everyone, even when not logged in.

Comment: As I see it: You should contact your plugin developer or downgrade you php version, or hack it some way to work with this new php version (for that you need to investigate the errors instead of hiding them :)

Comment: Plugin developer said they aren't maintaining the plugin anymore. I've tried some basic fixes but nothing works. The error is absolutely nothing major, and the PHP version can't be changed. I just need the errors hidden. I'll work on it later to get it to work with no errors, but it's on a live site and I don't want visitors seeing this.

Comment: What is the version of PHP you are using?  EE 2.5.5 was released in 2012!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is error suppression, you can find more info on it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)  
Code example

```
class foo {
    public function bar() {
        echo 1;
    }
}
foo::bar(); // Strict standards: Non-static method foo::bar() should not be called statically
@foo::bar(); // no warning
```

The @ symbol will suppress any error resulting in the fopen.

Comment: Whats this got to do with a NON Static Method error

Comment: There really isn't a place for me to put this I think? As RiggsFolly said, it's a non-static method error due to a newer PHP version.

Comment: Well I would assume the it's not causing a fatal error, just throwing a warning. If you were to add a @ before the call, it should suppress the warning from showing at all from the out of scope method. I've updated my answer to reflect, I could be misunderstanding the question tho :/

Comment: I was able to hunt down the problem function call and this worked!!! Thank you so much!!!